# XSLT removing nodes not matching a attribute value

Tags: xslt-1.0

I am trying to remove nodes from an xml if certain attribute values are not matching. Here is my XML:

```
<CONFIGURATIONS>
<CONFIG1 DOMAIN="CAE" FOCUS="IN" STATUS="ACTIVE" >
    <ATTR>1<ATTR>
</CONFIG1>
<CONFIG1 DOMAIN="CAE" FOCUS="OUT" STATUS="INACTIVE" >
    <ATTR>2<ATTR>
</CONFIG1>
    <CONFIG1 DOMAIN="CAE" FOCUS="OUT" STATUS="ACTIVE" >
    <ATTR>2<ATTR>
</CONFIG1>
    <CONFIG1 DOMAIN="MFG" FOCUS="OUT" STATUS="ACTIVE" >
    <ATTR>3<ATTR>
</CONFIG1>
</CONFIGURATIONS>
```

I want to remove the nodes not do not have the DOMAIN value as CAE and the FOCUS is not OUT and the STATUS is not ACTIVE.

```
<CONFIGURATIONS>    
    <CONFIG1 DOMAIN="CAE" FOCUS="OUT" STATUS="ACTIVE" >
    <ATTR>2<ATTR>
</CONFIG1>
```

I am using the following xslt:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
         <xsl:copy>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
          </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="SM_CONFIG_ITEM [@DOMAIN !='CAE' and @FOCUS !='OUT' and @STATUS != 'INACTIVE']"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But it is not producing the desired output. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> <xsl:template match="SM_CONFIG_ITEM [@DOMAIN !='CAE' and @FOCUS !='OUT' and @STATUS != 'INACTIVE']"/>
> ```
>
> But it is not producing the desired output. What am I doing wrong?

You want the element to be matched when *one* of the `!=` conditions is satisfied -- but the above match pattern specifies that *all* of the `!=` conditions must be satisfied.

**Solution**:

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match=
  "CONFIG1[not(@DOMAIN='CAE' and @FOCUS='OUT' and @STATUS='ACTIVE')]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<CONFIGURATIONS>
    <CONFIG1 DOMAIN="CAE" FOCUS="IN" STATUS="ACTIVE" >
        <ATTR>1</ATTR>
    </CONFIG1>
    <CONFIG1 DOMAIN="CAE" FOCUS="OUT" STATUS="INACTIVE" >
        <ATTR>2</ATTR>
    </CONFIG1>
    <CONFIG1 DOMAIN="CAE" FOCUS="OUT" STATUS="ACTIVE" >
        <ATTR>2</ATTR>
    </CONFIG1>
    <CONFIG1 DOMAIN="MFG" FOCUS="OUT" STATUS="ACTIVE" >
        <ATTR>3</ATTR>
    </CONFIG1>
</CONFIGURATIONS>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<CONFIGURATIONS>
   <CONFIG1 DOMAIN="CAE" FOCUS="OUT" STATUS="ACTIVE">
      <ATTR>2</ATTR>
   </CONFIG1>
</CONFIGURATIONS>
```

Comment: Even though I did not paste the exact xslt, your solution pointed my mistake. Thank.